# Android: How can I Convert String to Date?

Tags: android, string, date, casting

I store current time in database each time application starts by user.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    String str = c.getTime().toString();
    Log.i("Current time", str);
```

In database side, I store current time as string (as you see in above code). Therefore, when I load it from database, I need to cast it to Date object. I saw some samples that all of them had used "DateFormat". But my format is exactly as same as Date format. So, I think there is no need to use "DateFormat". Am I right?

Is there anyway to directly cast this String to Date object? I want to compare this stored time with current time.

---

**update**

Thanks all. I used following code:

```
private boolean isPackageExpired(String date){
        boolean isExpired=false;
        Date expiredDate = stringToDate(date, "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zz yyyy");        
        if (new Date().after(expiredDate)) isExpired=true;
        
        return isExpired;
    }
    
    private Date stringToDate(String aDate,String aFormat) {
    
      if(aDate==null) return null;
      ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);
      SimpleDateFormat simpledateformat = new SimpleDateFormat(aFormat);
      Date stringDate = simpledateformat.parse(aDate, pos);
      return stringDate;            
    
   }
```

Answer (score 504, accepted):

From String to Date

```
String dtStart = "2010-10-15T09:27:37Z";  
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");  
try {  
    Date date = format.parse(dtStart);  
    System.out.println(date);  
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

From Date to String

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");  
try {  
    Date date = new Date();  
    String dateTime = dateFormat.format(date);
    System.out.println("Current Date Time : " + dateTime); 
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

Comment: Exactly - it's better to apply some standard form to the date string before storing it in the database. In this case http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: For a more strictly working solution on "string to date", it's convenient to add  "format.setLenient(false);" before the try...catch block. In this way the check of a formerly correct string date will be better.

Comment: I don't believe that `SimpleDateFormat.format()` throws an exception

Comment: if your SDK version greater or equal to Marshmallow then use like this

`SimpleDateFormat dateFormat =new SimpleDateFormat(""yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"", Locale.getDefault());`

Comment: i am tring to convert string in format of dd/mm/Y to date but when i convert, no matter what date i choose, it returns day as 27, month and year are correctly returned.

Answer (score 20):

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date d = dateFormat.parse(datestring)
```

Comment: it's not suppose to parse String as a variable? Because this way, it's trying to parse the word "string".

Answer (score 7):

```
     import java.text.ParseException;
     import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
     import java.util.Date;
     public class MyClass 
     {
     public static void main(String args[]) 
     {
     SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");

     String dateInString = "Wed Mar 14 15:30:00 EET 2018";

     SimpleDateFormat formatterOut = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");


     try {

        Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
        System.out.println(date);
        System.out.println(formatterOut.format(date));

         } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }
    }
```

> here is your Date object **date**
>   and the output is :

**Wed Mar 14 13:30:00 UTC 2018**

**14 Mar 2018**

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6):

using SimpleDateFormat or DateFormat class through

for e.g.

```
try{
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); // here set the pattern as you date in string was containing like date/month/year
Date d = sdf.parse("20/12/2011");
}catch(ParseException ex){
    // handle parsing exception if date string was different from the pattern applying into the SimpleDateFormat contructor
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `java.time` in Android now, either by using [Android API Desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support) or importing the [ThreeTenAbp](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

With `java.time` enabled, you can do the same operations with less code and less errors.

Let's assume you are passing a `String` containing a datetime formatted in ISO standard, just as the currently accepted answer does.
Then the following methods and their usage in a `main` may show you how to convert from and to `String`:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String dtStart = "2010-10-15T09:27:37Z";
    ZonedDateTime odt = convert(dtStart);
    System.out.println(odt);
}
```

and

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String dtStart = "2010-10-15T09:27:37Z";
    OffsetDateTime odt = convert(dtStart);
    System.out.println(odt);
}
```

will print the line

```
2010-10-15T09:27:37Z
```

when there are the corresponding methods

```java
public static OffsetDateTime convert(String datetime) {
    return OffsetDateTime.parse(datetime);
}
```

or

```java
public static ZonedDateTime convert(String datetime) {
    return ZonedDateTime.parse(datetime);
}
```

but of course not in the same class, that would not compile...

There's a `LocalDateTime`, too, but that would not be able to parse a zone or offset.

If you want to use custom formats for parsing or formatting output, you can utilize a `DateTimeFormatter`, maybe like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String dtStart = "2010-10-15T09:27:37Z";
    String converted = ZonedDateTime.parse(dtStart)
                                    .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
                                                    "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zz uuuu",
                                                    Locale.ENGLISH
                                                )
                                            );
    System.out.println(converted);
}
```

which will output

```
Fri Oct 15 09:27:37 Z 2010
```

For an `OffsetDateTime`, you would need to adjust the pattern a little:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String dtStart = "2010-10-15T09:27:37Z";
    String converted = OffsetDateTime.parse(dtStart)
                                    .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
                                                    "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss xxx uuuu",
                                                    Locale.ENGLISH
                                                )
                                            );
    System.out.println(converted);
}
```

This will produce a (slightly) different output:

```
Fri Oct 15 09:27:37 +00:00 2010
```

That's because a `ZonedDateTime` considers named time zones with changing offsets (due to daylight saving times or anything similar) while an `OffsetDateTime` just *knows* an offset from UTC.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a good idea to be careful with the Locale upon which `c.getTime().toString();` depends.

One idea is to store the time in seconds (e.g. [UNIX time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)). As an `int` you can easily compare it, and then you just convert it to string when displaying it to the user.

Answer (score 1):

```
String source = "24/10/17";

String[] sourceSplit= source.split("/");

int anno= Integer.parseInt(sourceSplit[2]);
int mese= Integer.parseInt(sourceSplit[1]);
int giorno= Integer.parseInt(sourceSplit[0]);

    GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
  calendar.set(anno,mese-1,giorno);
  Date   data1= calendar.getTime();
  SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("20yy-MM-dd");

    String   dayFormatted= myFormat.format(data1);

    System.out.println("data formattata,-->"+dayFormatted);
```