# Parsing date exception - Unparsable date

Tags: android, date, simpledateformat

I struggle with I guess trivial problem, but I don't see anything wrong here:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
String strDate = "2014-12-07T13:35:08.030Z";
try
{
    return format.parse(strDate);
}
catch (ParseException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.e("Problem with formatting date", strDate);
}
```

I'm getting **java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2014-12-07T13:35:08.030Z" (at offset 19)**

Any idea what is still wrong here?

Comment: `("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573250/android-how-can-i-convert-string-to-date just take a look at this link it may solve your problem dear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) it appears that Android-SimpleDateFormat does not support the Z-symbol (which is NOT a literal but a valid ISO-identifier and synonym for UTC+00:00).

So the pattern symbol Z only understands offsets like -0800, but not "Z". Just using apostrophs is not a sufficient workaround. You also need to set the timezone explicitly to UTC respective GMT+00:00 if you have your input ending with "Z". Something like that (not tested):

```
String input = "2014-12-07T13:35:08.030Z";
SimpleDateFormat format;

if (input.endsWith("Z")) {
  format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
  format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
} else {
  format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
}

try {
    return format.parse(input);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.e("Problem with formatting date", input);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just forget (') single quotation around Z in SimpleDateFormat :

'Z' instead of Z