# How to convert String to Date which can be store in database?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-datepicker, android-date

I use a DataPicker and in the method `onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,int dayOfMonth)` I get year , monthOfYear and dayOfMonth, how I can merge this 3 int in a single Date which I can use to store in a database?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android, How can I Convert String to Date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573250/android-how-can-i-convert-string-to-date)

Comment: Have you searched on internet before posting question? There are LOT of similar questions

Comment: If your output is int then you could use String.value Of(your int values in your format);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this

```
Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
    {
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        updateLabel();
    }
};

private void updateLabel() 
{
    String myFormat = "MM/dd/yy"; //In which format you need put here
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);

    textview.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: ok, it works, but if now I want to use this date that I have store in a database and for example execute some code when the date stored is equal to the corrent date in the device?

Comment: @Slaiv206 then you have to compare both dates . get the system date(device date) and get your date from database and compare them both and do whatever you are trying to do ...

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate a calendar:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Use it's methods to set the date:

```
cal.set(int year, int month, int day);
```

Then either store it as a timestamp integer

```
cal.getTimeInMillis()
```

or as a String

```
cal.toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert it to a `String` in the format `dd/mm/yyyy` using `SimpleDateFormatter`.

Then when you want to retrieve it, use some `String` manipulation to retrieve each individual component and construct a `Date` object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

private void datePicker(Date initialDate) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    if (initialDate != null) {
        cal.setTime(initialDate);
    }
    new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            String data = String.format("%02d/%02d/%04d", dayOfMonth, monthOfYear + 1, year);
            try {
                Date newDate = format.parse(data);
                saveMyDate(newDate);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
}

private void saveMyDate(Date newDate) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Calendar to set year, month, day

```
 GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
 cal.set(GregorianCalendar.YEAR, year);
 cal.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
 cal.set(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
```

and store as milli seconds

```
cal.getTimeInMillis();
```