# How filter data by month/year

Tags: java, android, listview

I have an Income model like this

```
@Table(name = "Income") public class Income extends Model {
    @Column(name = "AmountDate")
    public String amountDate;

    @Column(name = "Amount")
    public int amount; 

    @Column(name = "Day")
    public int day;

    @Column(name = "Month")
    public int month;

    @Column(name = "Year")
    public int year;
}
```

I would like to filter data from database like it is shown below. In listView month/year like this
[image]

And on ListViewItem click i would like to display all data for selected month/year.

**So, my question is how to display month/year (if data for month exists in database) in listView?**

Comment: How is that "filtering"? Seems you're just showing the data. Of course, now knowing that `amountDate` contains, it's difficult to say what you're trying to do. --- *Why* is `amountDate` a `String` and not a date type, e.g. `java.util.Date` or `java.time.LocalDate`?

Comment: I would like to group data by month/year and when listview item is clicked then open new fragment with all data for selected month/year.. 
I had some trouble with dates so I decide to save it like this.

Comment: If you would like to **group**, why did you say **filter**? Please edit question to clarify it.

Comment: btw, using pascal case for a column's name is a bad practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use 2 different ways

1. you can create a function called `group` and should look like code below:

   ```
   fun group(list : List<Income>) : Map<String,List<Income>> {    
       val map = HashMap<String,List<Income>>()
       list.foreach { 
           val month = getMonthOf(it.amountDate)
           if(map.contains(mounth)){
               map[month].add(it);
           } else {
               val arrayList = ArrayList<Income>()
               arrayList.add(it)
               map[month] = arrayList
           }
        }
     return map
   }
   ```

where `getMonthOf` is a method that will extract year+mouth of the income using `Date` class

then you can simply use `RecyclerView` and then create your custom list

better to use List that its items is also list.
see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34569217/how-to-add-a-recyclerview-inside-another-recyclerview) for this

and for parsing date see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573250/android-how-can-i-convert-string-to-date)

2.instead of saveing date in one field you can save it in three(year and mount and day) in your data base and you can simply filter your list and create map like first way I send here

so It is `getMonthOf` code for get unique string for every month of year:

```
fun getMonthOf(income:Income) = "${income.year}/${income.month}"
```

now you can simply send your map to your adapter and make your list

Comment: I' already have separate fields for day, month, year. 
I will try like you said so... thanks.

Comment: Could you please update your code with these three fields I've added.. 
I have some trouble with that

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I need convert this kotlin code to java.. It will take some time.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create custome Listview for this kind of operation on listview,

you can refere this [Link](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/) hope this will help you.