# How to delete some character from respone in Java?

Tags: java, android, string, retrofit2

I have some string respone date like this:

```
2018-11-30 12:00:00
```

and i want just get the time, so i want like this:

```
12.00
```

and my question, can we delete some character like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String apiDateString = "2018-11-30 12:00:00"; // in this case, your string from api
Date apiDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(apiDateString); // convert api date string to date
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh.mm");
String yourDateString = formatter.format(apiDate);
```

I think you want this.

**Edited with little comment.**

1. convert string to date. (apiDateString to apiDate)
2. create new format for what you want to form. In this case, 12.00
3. convert apiDate to your format. (apiDate -> 12.00)

Comment: yap i think this is work, but why always go to exceptions

Comment: @Uray Febri, Can you share what exception is??

Comment: Happy to hear that. :)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to use SimpleDateFormat so something like:

```
Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh.mm");
String folderName = formatter.format(today);
```

Based on your comment try:

```
int index = time.indexOf(‘:’);
int start = index -2;
int end = index + 2;
String newTime = time.substring(start,end);
```

Comment: Thank you for response, but i have data respone from api is String and the value is 2018-11-30 12:00:00, and i want just get the time like 12.00

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat mdformat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        String strDate = "Current Time : " + mdformat.format(calendar.getTime());
        display(strDate);
```

Comment: thank you for respone, but how replace the time when String value from api is 2018-11-30 12:00:00 and i want to just get the time like 12.00

Comment: You just need to format it. [Here might have answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454315/how-do-you-format-date-and-time-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SimpleDateFormat` to get time and then replace : by .
I hope it can help your problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8573343/10098766).
Use SimpleDateFormat to format you date.

From String to Date

```
// Convert from string to date
String yourDate = "2018-11-30 12:00:00";  
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = format.parse(yourDate);

//Use calender instead of date to getHours and minute, due to deprecated
Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);
calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+"."+calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)); //12.0
```

Comment: this always go to exception

Comment: Hi, i have edited my draft answer, above code can still be optimised. Found out parsing the incorrect format.